# Two sliding menus with different size

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I used [enter link description here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

as a library. I wanna to have right & left menu with different size. and I used this code

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

public class ActivityStartup extends Activity {

```
private ImageView next;
private ImageView imagmaster;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    // set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // configure the SlidingMenu
    final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);


    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
      int width = display.widthPixels;
     int menu_width = width - (width / 3);
      if (menu_width < 100) {
           menu_width = 100;
       }



    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    View view = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    menu.setMenu(view);

    final SlidingMenu menu2 = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu2.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu2.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu2.setBehindWidth(menu_width / 2);  generated method stub

    menu2.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu2.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu2.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    menu2.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    View view2 = G.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu2, null);
    menu2.setMenu(view2);

    view2.findViewById(R.id.imgIconTamasBaMa).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(ActivityStartup.this,ActivityTamas.class);
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    imagmaster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagmaster);
    imagmaster.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent v = new Intent(ActivityStartup.this, ActivityVideoList.class);
            startActivity(v);

        }
    });

    next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent n = new Intent(ActivityStartup.this, ActivityVideoSearch.class);
            startActivity(n);

        }
    });
}
```

}

But when I want to move the bigger one, both of them will appear